# Guardar datos de log en HashMap

Tags: java

Lo que deseo realizar es guardar cada petición de un acceslog en un `hashmap`, pero no se esta realizando el guardado. Por favor alguien ve el fallo ???

JAVA:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;


public class BuscarPatrones {

    static String inici = "GET / HTTP/1.1";
    static String fi = "HelloWorldExample";
/**
* @param args
*/
public static void main(String[] args) {

    File f = new File( "C:/Users/Marc/Desktop/access-logs.txt" );
    BufferedReader entrada;
     HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> Patrones = 
                new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<String>patron=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String>p=new ArrayList<String>();
    String linea="";
    int cont=0;

    try {
        entrada = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( f ) );

        while(entrada.ready()){
            linea = entrada.readLine();
            linea = linea.substring(linea.indexOf("+0100]") + 8);


            if(!linea.contains(inici)){
                patron.add(linea);
            }else{

                cont++;
                crearpatrones(Patrones,patron,cont);    
                patron.clear();
            }


}}catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}


    /*
     * --------------------Resultado general del programa----------------
     * 
     * for (Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry : Patrones.entrySet()) {
          String key = entry.getKey();
          ArrayList<String> value = entry.getValue();
          System.out.println(key);
          System.out.println(value);

    }*/



}

private static void crearpatrones(HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> patrones, ArrayList<String> patron2,int contador) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String petición="Petición";
    petición= petición+contador;

    //--------------Aqui accede con la info correcta---------------------

    //System.out.println(petición);
    //System.out.println(patron2);

    patrones.put(petición,patron2);

return; 

}
}
```

ACCESLOG:

```
https://mega.nz/#!mU9l3QaS!JZw7wQEqagjATFrfYgy8xkcnVzmV2nDhyt7o_6jqyaw

127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:30:30 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11485 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:30:31 +0100] "GET /favicon.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 21630 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:30:32 +0100] "GET /tomcat.css HTTP/1.1" 200 5926 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:30:33 +0100] "GET /tomcat.png HTTP/1.1" 200 5103 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:30:33 +0100] "GET /asf-logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 17811 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:30:33 +0100] "GET /bg-upper.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3103 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:30:33 +0100] "GET /bg-nav.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1401 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:30:33 +0100] "GET /bg-nav.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1401 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:30:33 +0100] "-" 400 - 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:30:37 +0100] "GET /bg-middle.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1918 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:30:37 +0100] "GET /bg-button.png HTTP/1.1" 200 713 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:31:03 +0100] "GET /examples HTTP/1.1" 302 - 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:31:03 +0100] "GET /examples/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1156 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:31:05 +0100] "GET /examples/servlets HTTP/1.1" 302 - 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:31:06 +0100] "GET /examples/servlets/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6596 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:31:09 +0100] "GET /examples/servlets/images/return.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 1231 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:31:10 +0100] "GET /examples/servlets/images/code.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 292 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:31:10 +0100] "GET /examples/servlets/images/execute.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 1242 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:31:18 +0100] "GET /examples/servlets/servlet/HelloWorldExample HTTP/1.1" 200 400 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:31:59 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11458 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:31:59 +0100] "GET /tomcat.css HTTP/1.1" 200 5926 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:32:00 +0100] "GET /favicon.2 HTTP/1.1" 200 21630 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:32:00 +0100] "GET /tomcat.png HTTP/1.1" 200 5103 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:32:00 +0100] "GET /asf-logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 17811 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:32:00 +0100] "GET /bg-nav.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1401 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:32:00 +0100] "v.png HTTP/1.1 " 400 - 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:32:02 +0100] "GET /bg-upper.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3103 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:32:03 +0100] "GET /bg-middle.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1918 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:32:03 +0100] "GET /bg-button.png HTTP/1.1" 200 713 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:32:08 +0100] "GET /examples HTTP/1.1" 302 - 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:32:08 +0100] "GET /examples/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1156 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:32:11 +0100] "GET /examples/servlets HTTP/1.1" 302 - 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:32:13 +0100] "GET /examples/servlets/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6596 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:32:18 +0100] "GET /examples/servlets/images/return.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 1231 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:32:19 +0100] "GET /examples/servlets/images/code.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 292 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:32:19 +0100] "GET /examples/servlets/images/execute.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 1242 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:32:21 +0100] "GET /examples/servlets/servlet/HelloWorldExample HTTP/1.1" 200 400 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:33:04 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11485 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:33:04 +0100] "GET /favicon.3 HTTP/1.1" 200 21630 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:33:05 +0100] "GET /tomcat.css HTTP/1.1" 200 5926 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:33:06 +0100] "GET /tomcat.png HTTP/1.1" 200 5103 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:33:06 +0100] "GET /bg-upper.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3103 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:33:06 +0100] "GET /asf-logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 17811 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:33:06 +0100] "GET /bg-nav.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1401 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:33:06 +0100] "GET /bg-nav.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1401 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:33:06 +0100] "-" 400 - 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:33:08 +0100] "GET /bg-middle.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1918 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:33:08 +0100] "GET /bg-button.png HTTP/1.1" 200 713 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:33:15 +0100] "GET /examples HTTP/1.1" 302 - 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:33:15 +0100] "GET /examples/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1156 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:33:19 +0100] "GET /examples/servlets HTTP/1.1" 302 - 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:33:20 +0100] "GET /examples/servlets/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6596 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:33:21 +0100] "GET /examples/servlets/images/code.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 292 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:33:22 +0100] "GET /examples/servlets/images/return.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 1231 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:33:22 +0100] "GET /examples/servlets/images/execute.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 1242 
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2016:19:33:25 +0100] "GET /examples/servlets/servlet/HelloWorldExample HTTP/1.1" 200 400
```

Comment: ¿Qué significa "algo estoy haciendo mal"? ¿Error de compilación o ejecución? ¿Y qué error? ¿Resultados inesperados? ¿Qué resultados esperabas y que resultados obtienes?

Comment: Buenas!! el problema son resultados inesperdos !! Me explico: Tengo mi fichero acceslog.txt con una serie de peticiones. Mi intención es conseguir un hashmap cuya relacion key-value sea peticionX-con su correspondiente peticion ( siendo x un valor para numerar las distintas que existan) El problema es que al acceder a la funcion para meter estos datos en el hashmap...compruebo que son lo que quiero introducir, pero luego al visualizarlo ...el reasultado es peticion29 - y su correspondiente peticion !!!

Answer (score 1):

Nunca aclarastes muy bien tu problema. Pero sí hay un detalle que de seguro te va a causar problemas, y es con esta sentencia:

```
patron.clear();
```

En la sentencia anterior, ejecutas el método `crearpatrones`, al que le pasas una referencia a `patron` y que usas para asignarlo al `HashMap`.

Pues cuando haces el `patron.clear()`, estás trabajando con el mismo objeto que le acabas de asignar al `HashMap`. Ambos tienen una referencia al mismo objeto. No son copias distintas. De modo, que sin querer, estás eliminando los valores dentro del `ArrayList` que le acabas de asignar al `HashMap`.

Una forma de arreglar el problema es de crear una nueva lista en vez de ejecutar el método `clear`. De esta forma te aseguras de trabajar con una lista distinta a la que acabas de agregar al `HashMap`:

```
patron = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Si te entiendo bien, tu idea es de guardar *HashMaps* de peticiones en el *AccessLog* agrupado por acceso raíz (tu constante *inici*).

Como [sstan](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/18951/sstan) ya explicó, *Java* pasa referencias a métodos, no copias. Así que lo que tu código hace es guardar el mismo *HashMap* con cada bloque de peticiones y con el próximo bloque lo vacía de nuevo ( `patron.clear()` ).

Lo que podrías hacer es en vez de:

```
while(entrada.ready()){
    linea = entrada.readLine();
    linea = linea.substring(linea.indexOf("+0100]") + 8);


    if(!linea.contains(inici)){
        patron.add(linea);
    }else{

        cont++;
        crearpatrones(Patrones,patron,cont);    
        patron.clear();
    }
}
```

... es usar:

```
while(entrada.ready()){
    linea = entrada.readLine();
    linea = linea.substring(linea.indexOf("+0100]") + 8);


    if(linea.contains(inici)){
        // si hay un bloque anterior, guardalo
        if (patron.size()>0) crearpatrones(Patrones, patron, ++cont);
        patron = new ArrayList<String>();
    }else{
        patron.add(linea);
    }
}
// Fin de log, guarda el ultimo bloque
if (patron.size()>0) crearpatrones(Patrones, patron, ++cont);
```

Además de eso te recomiendo seguir algunas convenciones para facilitar a otros a orientarse en tu código:

1. Las constantes se escriben en mayúsculas, las palabras, separadas por `_`.
    `static String INICI = "...";`.
2. Las clases empiezan con mayúsculas, las variables y los métodos con minúsculas.
    `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> patrones =...`.
3. Las palabras en clases, variables y métodos, se separan por *camelCasing*.
    `public void crearPatrones(...){...`.

Comment: Siento estos detalles que no sabia...gracias por la recomendacion. el problema son resultados inesperdos !! Me explico: Tengo mi fichero acceslog.txt con una serie de peticiones. Mi intención es conseguir un hashmap cuya relacion key-value sea peticionX-con su correspondiente peticion ( siendo x un valor para numerar las distintas que existan) El problema es que al acceder a la funcion para meter estos datos en el hashmap...compruebo que son lo que quiero introducir, pero luego al visualizarlo ...el reasultado es peticion29 - y su correspondiente peticion

Answer (score 0):

Si el problema es por el orden en el que se muestran en el loop, esto se debe a que el HashMap no itera en el orden que se almacena. Si deseas iterar en el orden que almacenaste, usa [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

Un ejemplo de lo anterior sería:

```
HashMap<Integer,String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put(1,"uno");
map1.put(2,"dos");
map1.put(3,"tres");
// La salida no es 1, 2, 3
for(Entry<Integer,String> entry : map1.entrySet()){
    System.out.println(entry.getKey());
}
```

Con LinkedHashMap:

```
HashMap<Integer,String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map2.put(1,"uno");
map2.put(2,"dos");
map2.put(3,"tres");
// La salida es 1, 2, 3
for(Entry<Integer,String> entry : map2.entrySet()){
    System.out.println(entry.getKey());
}
```

Comment: Hola @Victor. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so] y gracias por aportar! ¿Podrías ejemplificar con algún fragmento de código cómo es que tu recomendación respondería a la pregunta? La idea es sumar respuestas con la mayor calidad posible